# Get the closest value from mysql table

Tags: mysql

This might be a simple one, but since I don't have much knowledge about MySQL I don't know how to do this, This is what I basically  want,

I have a query like this

//time format "yyyy-MM-dd"

```
SELECT ID 
FROM `id_table` 
WHERE time > "2012-01-05 " AND time < "2012-01-10";
```

But in the `id_table` I have data only up to 2012-01-04 then it starts again from "2012-01-20", so above query would return null. Is there a any way where I can retrieve the last data record from the table, as for this example can I get the ID of  2012-01-04 date from the table when I query like this

```
SELECT ID 
FROM `id_table` 
WHERE time > "2012-01-05"
```

Comment: Would SELECT id, date FROM id_table ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1 work?  Could probably use some application code to check if your first query returned 0 results, and then if so do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for the one (i assume max ID) `ID` of the row with the nearest `time` to 2010-01-05?

```
SELECT MAX(ID) as LastId FROM id_table 
WHERE time = (SELECT MAX(time) 
              FROM id_table WHERE time < '2012-01-05')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID FROM id_table
WHERE time between
  least((select max(time) from id_table), "2012-01-05") AND "2012-01-10";
```

Note that `between` will get data from `"2012-01-10" and ("2012-01-05" OR "2012-01-05)`

Answer (score 0):

To get the record closest to the given time ( you could easily tweak this if you care about dealing with duplicates, if that doesn't matter then this alone should suffice)

```
 SELECT
    ID
 FROM
    id_table
 ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(time, '2012-01-05'))
 LIMIT 1
```

NOTE: If the time field is a time value yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss then you can use TIMEDIFF for a more accurate comparison.

OP If you will explain more on how you would like to handle different cases I can tweak this example to suit them. Cheers.

Comment: +1 This one will work even if there is an exact match. And if OP requires only records before the given date he can add a where clause or remove the absolute value.